# Woocommerce API call add multiple sites

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce

Please see my API call in order to get Woocommerce orders in my PHP site.
Can one adjust this in order the get order data from more than one URL/ stores?

The data is used in a PHP site in order to process orders. We have 3-4 Woocommerce stores which we want to manage in our own site.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.enterwebsite.co.za/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=20',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('api_keys:api_keys'));
    },
    data: {
      orderby: 'id',
      order: 'desc',
      per_page: 10,
      offset: 0
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response && Array.isArray(response)) {
        var orders = response.map(function(order) {
          var orderId = order.id;
          var clientName = order.billing && order.billing.first_name && order.billing.last_name ? (order.billing.first_name + ' ' + order.billing.last_name) : '';
          var orderDate = order.date_created ? new Date(order.date_created).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
            month: 'short',
            day: 'numeric',
            year: 'numeric'
          }) : '';
          var shipping = '';
          var delivery = '';
          var total = order.total ? parseFloat(order.total).toFixed(2) : '';

          if (order.shipping && order.shipping.address_1 && order.shipping.city && order.shipping.country) {
            shipping = order.shipping.address_1 + ', ' + order.shipping.city + ', ' + order.shipping.country;
          }

          if (order.meta_data && order.meta_data.length >= 7) {
            delivery = order.meta_data[5].value;
          }

          return [
            '<a href="od?oid=' + orderId + '" class="row-link order-number">' + orderId + '</a>',
            clientName,
            '<a href="#orderPreview' + orderId + '" data-toggle="modal" class="row-link" title="Preview"><i class="fas fa-eye" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Preview"></i></a>',
            orderDate,
            shipping,
            delivery,
            'R ' + total
          ];
        });

        var table = $('#newOrders').DataTable();
        table.clear().rows.add(orders).draw();
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid API response:', response);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('AJAX request error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built-in way of doing this. You would have to code your own endpoint that would allow you to do to that.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-woocommerce-rest-api-for-accessing-all-stores-on-multisite/ and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311967/rest-api-multisite-site-list/356864